# Mojo::UserAgent: get only the text

Tags: perl, dom, www-mechanize, mojolicious

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get( $url );
say $mech->text;
```

How could I get the same result with `Mojo::UserAgent`?
I tried this, but it doesn't return the same:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

say $ua->get( $url )->res->dom->all_text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply repeat what [method `text`](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/WWW-Mechanize/WWW/Mechanize.pm.html#text-) does: see [`as_text` in HTML::Element](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aElement#h-as_text-).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$ua->get( $url )->res->dom->all_text(0);
```

for untrimmed output. Or you may need some kind of traversal over child nodes.